# os.mkdir() returns error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python-3.x

a very simple code to create a directory:

```
ssh_path = f"{os.getenv('HOME')}/temp/.ssh"
print(ssh_path)
os.mkdir(ssh_path)
```

it prints the path of directory and ends up with error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myusername/temp/.ssh'
/Users/myusername/temp/.ssh
```

Comment: does `temp` already exist?

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova no. and if it exits it should be a different error per my understanding.

Comment: Then you need to tell `os.mkdir()` to create the parents as well.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use `os.makedirs()` to create the intermediate folders.

```
os.makedirs(ssh_path)
```

If you use `Path` from `pathlib`, you can do:

```
ssh_path = f"{os.getenv('HOME')}/temp/.ssh")
ssh = Path(ssh_path)
ssh.mkdir(parents=true)
```

Comment: os.makedirs() works! haven't tested method 2 with Path yet. Thanks

Comment: os.mkdir() -> $mkdir . 
os.makedirs() -> $mkdir -p